# AWS Codecommit Git Clone error : fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'codecommit'

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am trying to clone a repository from our private codecommit, I have necessary access, but whenever i try to clone locally, I am getting the error:

```
git clone codecommit::us-east-1://my-repo-name

fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'codecommit'
```

I encountered remote helper error before but for https which could be resolved by ssh keys, but this is the first time I have seen this.

Comment: I am having the same issue while I try to use git commands in Sourcetree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution for this. you have to have a version 3 or above version of python when you install git-remote-codecommit

```
pip install git-remote-codecommit
```

for some reason, it does not install correctly when python 2.7 is installed.

```
❯ git clone codecommit::us-east-1://my-repo-name
Cloning into 'my-repo-name'...
remote: Counting objects: 171562, done.
remote: processing
Receiving objects:  98% (118068/171562), 56.20 MiB | 3.09 MiB/s
```

it completed and worked properly afterwards.

Comment: I installed using `pip3 ...` on macOS. I have Python 3 installed as `python3`. What could be the issue I'm still having?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on macOS and venv with clear python 3 resolved it.

```
python3 -m venv ~/Documents/venv
source ~/Documents/venv/bin/activate
```

Once venv activated install git-remote-codecommit and clone your repository

```
pip install git-remote-codecommit
git clone codecommit::us-east-1://my-repo-name
```

Comment: Bravo @KaterynaB. Your solution with creating the virtual environment solved my problem too.

Comment: Thanks mate, you solved my million dollaer problem :)